# Why loading image asynchronously in iOS is creating memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display a large photo which is 21 MB in my collectionViewCell. The code below works fine but gets receivedLowMemoryWarning after repeated (10-20) times usage.

Note : I guess I was not clear what is repeated means. there are 10-20 cells displaying image, each image is around 21 MB.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    cell.photoView.image = image;
    return cell;
}
```

So I thought I should scale down the image in background and load the image. I modified above code to

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self setImageAsync:indexPath fileName:myTrumbImageFileName collectionView:collectionView];
    return cell;
}

-(void) setImageAsync:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath fileName:(NSString*) fileName collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIImage *smallImage = [image resizedImageToFitInSize:CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width*2, screenRect.size.height*2) scaleIfSmaller:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 1
      PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if(cell)
      {
        cell.photoView.image = smallImage;
        [[cell photoView] setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView transitionWithView:[cell photoView] duration:0.35 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{ [[cell photoView] setAlpha:1.0]; } completion:nil];
      }
    });        
  });
}
```

The above code receives low memory warning every time it runs. I expected it will solve the memory warning as I am now doing image operation in bg thread. So what is going wrong. Can some expert help me understand.

Comment: What do you man by "photo which is 21 MB"? The number of pixels or the file size? What is the width and height? The size in memory is width * height * 4.

Comment: The file size from doc directory is 21 MB. W = 3192 and H = 1600

Comment: "repeated (10-20) times usage", Is that displaying 10-20 at the same time? How many are in the collection view? What is the display size in the collection view?

Comment: That would suggest that you have an uncompressed image file, but if you're confident that the image dimensions is really 3192 x 1600, then that's fine. Regarding getting a memory warning every time you call this routine (which doesn't make sense because 21mb is not enough to consistently cause memory warnings), you can cache (in persistent storage, and optionally `NSCache`, too) the resized image so you don't have to reload the large image every time. Also, I'd suggest resizing it on the basis of the cell dimensions (times scale) rather than the screen dimensions.

Comment: @Rob The second sentence" "but gets receivedLowMemoryWarning after repeated (10-20) times usage"

Comment: @zaph - Yeah. But he also says "The above code receives low memory warning every time it runs." Frankly, if these are full screen cells, then the question is why isn't memory getting released. (It could also be that he has some other memory leak, but the large memory consumption of this routine is what triggers the memory warning.) Using "Allocations" tool in "Instruments" would help diagnose that. If they are not full screen cells, the question is why is he resizing to the size of the screen.

Comment: There is also doubt of what "every time" means. What It could also be that the OP is displaying smaller images and should scale the images to the display size.

Comment: Agreed. Until this question is clarified, there's no point in further guessing.

Comment: I have edited the question.  I guess I was not clear what is repeated means. there are 10-20 cells displaying image, each image is around 21 MB.

Comment: How many are displayed at once and what is the size on the screen of the images, not the size of the actual image. If several them memory usage is going to be large fast.

Comment: I have close to 10 pictures which are in individual table view cells. All pictures occupy the whole screen.

Comment: Do you release in some manner the images that are not displayed? Have you look at the memory with Instruments andd Mark Generation, see my answer.

Comment: "I have close to 10 pictures which are in individual table view cells. All pictures occupy the whole screen." ... OK, then that means that you generally won't have more than one or two instantiated at any given point in time, so there's no reason that this should result in memory pressure. This assumes, of course, that `resizedImageToFitInSize` is not leaking (you haven't shared this with us and if you're doing Core Graphics stuff there, it's easy to leak if you don't do that right ... shift+command+B can find those sorts of leaks). If not, you have to use instruments to identify leak, if any.

Comment: For Apple tutorials on types of memory issues and how to use Instruments to diagnose and resolve, see WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) or WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242).

Comment: The resizedImageToFitInSize is taken from https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize

Comment: I don't see any obvious leaks there, so the problem is likely to rest elsewhere. Instruments will help you identify what allocations are taking place but not getting released. Hopefully the above videos will familiarize you with the tools to track down memory problems. But there are no obvious memory issues in the code in the question, nor in that resize routine you reference.

Answer (score 0):

Memory warnings are not about executing big tasks in the foreground.
iOS will trigger a Memory Warning when the memory pressure becomes too high.

In your case, you are loading a 21MB image in RAM. If the RAM is already almost full, iOS will send a memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

To find where the memory is being held, that seems to be the issue use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Mark Generation (Heapshot) in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically the method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an iteration of your code and take another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on (For Xcode 5 and lower you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the app to run, stop recording, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the images of that size in memory you will eventually run out of memory.

Perhaps a better approach is to resize and cache each image you download and not hold the original 21mb file in memory. Also, remember that if the images are 21mb compress (JPG) it will be larger in memory once decoded, so each image in memory is more than 21mb.

If you're not against using a library check out: https://github.com/path/FastImageCache